# Просьба наглядно объяснить как читать документацию к библиотеке discord на Python

Tags: python, discord.py

С таким вопросом, я скорее всего покажусь вам абсолютно тупым, но **я не понимаю как читать эту документацию**, ну вот не понимаю, хоть ты тресни.

Comment: примите ответ, если он вам помог — галочка слева от ответа ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **я не понимаю как читать эту документацию**

Самые азы можно и даже лучше учить не из доков, а из чего-нибудь более "наглядного".

Иногда начинать сразу с документации — не очень удобно и понятно. Начать можно с тьюториала нарпимер. [Вот отличный по-русски](https://habr.com/ru/post/511454/). Ну а дальше — гугл.  ;)
Ну а если доки — то начинать с [Quick Start](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) наверно.

А вот минимальный код:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run('your token here')
```

- Импортируем библиотеку. `import discord`
- Создаем главный объект — `client = discord.Client()`
- Когда все запустилось:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
```

- И дальше читаем каждое сообщение, и если оно — `"$hello"`, то:

```
await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

Отсылаем "Hello!".

## Что еще?

Чтоб делать бота, также надо знать питон на хорошем уровне, в том числе [декораторы](https://tproger.ru/translations/demystifying-decorators-in-python/) и [асинки](https://tproger.ru/translations/asynchronous-programming-in-python/).

Comment: Азы как его запустить я знаю. У меня проблема как раз таки с более глубоким изучением. Но как на зло, нигде, кроме документации, не описано что-то более сложное, чем Quick Start

Comment: @VakhalayMahalay Ну, а если вы уже "продвинулись" то что, с доками не так?

Comment: Они мне не понятны сами по себе. Не знаю как это объяснить, возможно у меня случай критического идиотизма, но всë же.

Comment: @VakhalayMahalay Да ну, доки — это муторно, ты прав ;) Тогда гугли конкретный вопрос или здесь задавай и все будет ок.

Comment: Хорошо, вас понял кэп!

Comment: @VakhalayMahalay _Удачи!_ ;)